# Waiting for async execution before continuing for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I want to have a solution to the problem here. We need to have the 5 asterisk * printed before printing finished.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    delay();
    console.log('finished');
}

function delay() {
   setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('*');
    }, 1000)
}
```

One way that I can think of solving this is by using await keyword and modifying the code to something like below

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

async function processArray() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      await delay();
      console.log('done');
    }
}
```

and

```
function delay() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(console.log('*'));
        }, 1000)
    });
}
```

What are some other ways in which the goal can be achieved ? I want to change the original code minimally. I have just started async programming in node and would like to know the possible ways.
Also any pointers to resources where I can learn and implement various quirks and workarounds would be great !

Thanks!

Comment: Does the second way not work?

Comment: it does actually, but I was posed this question somewhere and wasn't told the answer to the same and hence I am wondering of any other ways :(

Comment: `const delay=n=>new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r, n))` ... then you can `await delay(1000)` in an `async` function of course

Answer (score 1):

As delay function is async, calling it inside a for loop will not give accurate results. I think you should use a recursive logic as below.

```
let i = 0;
delay(i);

function delay(i) {
    if (i < 5) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('*');
            i++;
            delay(i);
        }, 1000)
    }
    else {
        console.log('finished');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('*')
  }, i * 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking for other possible ways to solve this problem. Another way could also be this:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let progress = 0;

function processArray() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        delay();    
    }  
}

function delay() {
   setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('*');
      progress++;

      if(progress === arg.length){
          console.log('finished');
      } 

   }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem or answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also:

```js
Array.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], x => { setTimeout(() => console.log('*'), x * 1000) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
function PA(parms) {
  this.id = parms.id;
  this.ai = undefined;
  if ("maxCount" in parms)
    this.maxCount = parms.maxCount;
  this.count = 0;
}
PA.objs = [];
PA.prototype.ms  = 1000;
PA.prototype.maxCount = 5;
PA.prototype.stop = function() {
      if (this.ai) {
        clearInterval(this.ai);
        this.ai = undefined;
      }
  };
PA.prototype.start = function() {
      if (this.ai) this.stop();
      this.ai = setInterval("PA.objs[" + id + "].rn()", this.ms);
  };
PA.prototype.rn = function() {
    console.log("*");
    if (this.count<this.maxCount) {
      this.count += 1;
    }
    else {
      console.log("done.");
      this.stop();
    }
  };

var id = 0;
PA.objs[id] = new PA({id: id});
PA.objs[id].start();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an async task with timers, V8 engine of node.js removes the task from the stack and waits for the timer to count down. Thus, `console.log("finished")` is the only task that is left in the function stack in the beginning and the reason why it is printed on the screen first. It would give the same results even with the timers set to 0 ms.

Another solution would be like the following.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var counter = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    delay();
}

function delay() {
   setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('*');
        counter += 1
        if (counter === arr.length)
            print();
    }, 1000)
}

function print(){
    console.log('finished');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve your problem is to use Events, as in:

```
'use strict';
/* eslint-env node, es6 */

const EventEmitter = require('events');

/**
 * Count of running instances of the Event in delayedPrint.
 * @type {Number}
 */
let instances = 0;

/**
 * Prints message to console after delay milliseconds.
 *
 * @param  {String} message  - the message to print
 * @param  {Number} delay    - the number of milliseconds to delay printing
 */
const delayedPrint = (message, delay) => {
  const evt = new EventEmitter();

  message = (message || '').toString(); // assure message is a string
  delay = Number(delay) || 0; // assure delay is a number

  evt.on('start', () => { // uses setTimeout() to schedule an emit in the future
    instances++;
    setTimeout(() => {
      evt.emit('end');
    }, delay);
  });

  evt.on('end', () => { // what happens after delay milliseconds
    console.log(message);
    instances--;
    if (!instances) { // what happens after all running instances are complete.
      console.log('done');
    }
  });

  evt.emit('start'); // start delay
};

delayedPrint('It is now 10 seconds later!', 10 * 1000);
delayedPrint('It is now 5 seconds later!', 5 * 1000);
delayedPrint('It is now 1 second later!', 1 * 1000);
```